# connecting to Interbase version 5 from C#

Tags: c#, interbase

Does anyone know how to connect to older versions of `interbase` (version 5.5 / 5.6) using `.NET/C#`

I am not sure if the drivers for the latest versions of `interbase` will work or will eventually cause corruption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at IBProvider:
http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/index.html

They're declaring IB 4 & 5 support.

Comment: thanks I will check it out. It does not look like it is freeware though - do you know of any free solution that does this?

Comment: It is definitely **not** a freeware product. Unfortunately, I don't know any free .NET data providers for Interbase.